# Join table in Symfony 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, join

I just started object-oriented programming in Symfony 2, and I have a problem joining mysql tables.

I have two tables:

**kommuner**:
id,name,capacity

**Activities**:
id,name,kommune_id

*How do I join these tables in the entity files?*
This is my function in DefaultController:

```
public function aktiviteterAction()
{

    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
    $aktiviteter = $em->getRepository(Aktiviteter::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('default/aktiviteter.html.twig', [
        'aktiviteter' => $aktiviteter,
    ]);

}
```

and this is my entity, Kommune.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Kommune
 */
class Kommune
{
 /**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $capacity;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Kommune
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set capacity
 *
 * @param integer $capacity
 * @return Kommune
 */
public function setCapacity($capacity)
{
    $this->capacity = $capacity;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get capacity
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getCapacity()
{
    return $this->capacity;
}
}
```

and this is my Aktiviteter.php entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Aktiviteter
 */
class Aktiviteter
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $kommuneId;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Aktiviteter
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set kommuneId
 *
 * @param integer $kommuneId
 * @return Aktiviteter
 */
public function setKommuneId($kommuneId)
{
    $this->kommuneId = $kommuneId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get kommuneId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getKommuneId()
{
    return $this->kommuneId;
}



/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kommune")
 * @JoinColumn(name="kommune_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $kommune;

}
```

Can someone please explain how these table joins work in Symfony 2? I appreciate all kinds of help!

Comment: You have inserted Kommune entity 2 times.

Comment: Good point! See edit

Comment: Do you read the docs I've posted in my answer? If you need help to choose the right association type you need to update your question adding some infos about the relationship you needs between these entities (what these entities are and how these interacting each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose the right [Doctrine Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) depending by the relationship you want between these entities.

Other references useful to read for you:

- [entity-relationships-associations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) from the Symfony's Book.
- Then [Recipes about Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/index.html) from the Symfony's Cookbook.

**Update** based on comments and post edit:

> A OneToMany - ManyToOne relation could be [Unidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Aktiviteter
 */
class Aktiviteter
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;    

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Aktiviteter
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}    

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Kommune")
 * @JoinTable(name="kommunes")
 **/
private $kommunes;

}
```

> Or [Bidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional):

Like did by **@Isa Bek** answer

**NOTE**: [When mapping bidirectional associations it is important to understand the concept of the owning and inverse sides](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) and remember that you don't need to set the entity id of the relationship because Doctrine handle this automatically as you will see after the mapping will applied with the command: `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` from your console.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure which mapping I should use. I tried the first one (see edit), but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @MathiasLund Ok! Now I've a dinner but after I will update my answer :-)

Comment: Hi again :) Its weird because when I run "$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" it returns: "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.". Is that correct behaviour?

Comment: @MathiasLund Yes it's the correct behavior. About how to access the associated data you can learn all you need reading carefully the documentation I've linked in my answer. (you can't avoid reading the docs :-)). If you have some trouble update your post with your code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you want to use one to many relationship between **Kommune** and **Aktiviteler** entities.
In Kommune.php entity:

```
/**
 * Kommune
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Kommune
 {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Aktiviteter", mappedBy="kommune")
     */
    private $aktiviteler;

   /**
    * Other fields
    */
}
```

In Aktiviteter.php entity

```
/**
 * Aktiviteter
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Aktiviteter
{
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kommune", inversedBy="aktiviteler")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kommune_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
   private $kommune;

   /**
    * Other fields
   */
 }
```

I think, these codes would be useful for you.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said, but how do I call it in my function? :)

Comment: You can call like as `$aktiviteter = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YouBundleName:Aktiviteter')->findAll();`